# Deleted AppleColorEmoji@2x.ttf from my iOS device

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I read about a way to add iOS 8.3's new emojis to jailbroken iOS 8.1.2 devices and I made it but I deleted the iOS 8.1.2 file by mistake.

Now I want to get back to the old emojis. I deleted the tweak but now I don't have the iOS 8.1.2 AppleColorEmoji@2x.ttf file. I can't open the emoji keyboard as it crashes because the file doesn't exist.

How can I get the old file?

Comment: sounds like you should RESTORE your device.

Answer (score 5):

This file is copyrighted (or licensed) by Apple, so it will be difficult to find a download site for it. You can

- reset and restore your iPhone to iOS 8.3 (and lose the jailbreak for now)
- disable the Emoji keyboard for the time being